# MySQL : How to select record where begin date and end date between two dates of mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to select a room rate in which check-in date and check-out date is between a range of date specify. Those rates are named separately according to its conditions. Room costs are depends on the date selected. Here is my code:

**rate_eb**

```
rate_name     rate_starts     rate_ends     rate_discount     rate_min_stay
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Low Season    2013-05-01      2013-10-31    20                3            
High Season1  2013-11-01      2013-12-19    20                4
High Season2  2013-02-21      2013-04-31    20                4
Peak Season   2013-12-20      2014-02-20    20                5
```

**The conditions are:**

1. A booking must be in between **rate_starts** and **rate_ends**.
2. A total of nights stay must be greater or equal to **rate_min_stay**.
3. **rate_discount** is a percentage of discount from a master rate from another table. Saying if a master rate is 100, a rate of 80 will be applied to this booking.

Now, I'd like to get those data from rate_db with a date range - especially for rate_discount.  Here's my mySQL:

```
select rate_discount 
from rate_eb 
where rate_min_stay<='4' 
and reb_starts>='2013-06-19' 
and reb_ends<='2013-06-23'
```

From the code above. I expect rate_discount=20 from **Low Season** but all of the rate less than or equal to 4 are selected.

Now, please suggest me the solutions. How I can re-write my code to access the rate_discount between rate_starts and rate_ends.

Comment: Table description has `rate_starts` while query has `reb_date1`. Is that a typo?

Comment: @ypercube, Oh it's my fault. I tested it with mySQL and forgot to change it. Now it's changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the  visitor can enter a period, not just one date. What happens if the startdate of that period is in low season and the enddate in high season? Which rate would you like to see then?

```
select rate_discount 
from rate_eb 
where rate_min_stay <= abs( datediff( reb_date2, reb_date1 ) )
and reb_date1 between rate_starts and rate_ends
and reb_date2 between rate_starts and rate_ends
```

I'm assuming that reb_date1 is the startdate the visitor entered, and reb_date2 the enddate.

Comment: Hi Vivienne, your code looks more valuable but mySQL doesn't accept the date_diff() function. I checked phpmyadmin version - 3.5.7. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, updated the code to the correct method (datediff() in stead of date_diff())

Comment: Vivienne, your solution works! Thank you for your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

use to_date('dateInString','format') to convert string to date for reb_date1 and reb_date2 and use unquoted number value directly if you are doing a greater than comparision for rate_min_stay